# Changing script files used on the front end of a node backed website

Tags: node.js

I'm making a solitaire game using NodeJs and Express backend and phaser.io frontend. It will offer different layouts of cards to play.

I have the game working "just fine" alpha state, but with a single layout of cards setup in HTML like:

```
<script src="js/gameboards/data.js"></script>
<script src="js/tableau.js"></script>
```

where `data.js` is the file that describes the card layout, and `tableau.js` is the game logic. I have several different files in `/gameboards` and for the testing/building, I just change the filename when I want to change the layout.

`data.js` is not a JSON file, it's a JS object

```
let gameboard = {
    info: {
        title: "Standard",
        description: "6 columns of 5 cards"
    },
    [...]
    deal: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.vars.allstacks; i++) {
        etc...
```

That contains simple object data as well as object methods that define patterns and repetition (like multiple stacks, pyramids, etc) so it can't really be made into a JSON or other straight data file.

What I want to do is present a list of anchors/links to the player of the layout options. They'll click the link to get sent into `/game` with the layout they chose.

The method I thought of was to have `/index` send POST-data containing the `layoutname`. Then, in `/game`

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) { ... })
```

with the HTML template and `res.render` containing

```
<script src="js/gameboards/<layoutname>.js"></script>
```

to call the right file.

Is there a better way of doing this than what I listed above? It seems kludgey to me as if there would be a more 'nodey' and elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the way you describe you need to enable a templating engine like handlebars or Pug. For pug I do something like this:

In server:

```
const cdnAction = process.env.S3_CDN_ACTIVE;

app.route('*')
  .get( (req, res) => {
    const cdnCSSPath = `https://s3.amazonaws.com/${process.env.S3_BUCKET_CDN}/audience.css.gz`;
    res.render('home', { cdnActive, cdnPath, cdnCSSPath });
  });
```

In pug file 'home.pug' rendered above:

```
head
    if cdnActive === 'true'
        link(href=cdnCSSPath rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
    else
        link(href='/style/embed.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
```

Comment: Yeah so I'm using EJS, and I know it can be done like I describe with EJS, that's not the question. The question is about a better, more 'node-like' manner to accomplish the end result that I describe.